# WPF Datagrid with SelectedItem doesn't show updates to ViewModel property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpftoolkit

I have a ReadOnly DataGrid in a WPF UserControl bound to a ViewModel (VM) and a SelectedItem bound to a Property of the VM.
There are also two textboxes, one bound to a SelectedItem Property and one bound to a VM Property.

```xaml
<UserControl
    x:Class="PhoneAssistant.WPF.Features.ServiceRequests.ServiceRequestsMainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhoneAssistant.WPF.Features.ServiceRequests"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:ServiceRequestsMainViewModel}"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid
            Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="16,20,0,15"
            d:Background="LightCoral">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox
                Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0"
                Text="{Binding SelectedSR.BoundToSelected}" />
            <TextBox
                Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,5,0"
                Text="{Binding VmProperty}" />
        </Grid>
        <DataGrid
            Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            IsReadOnly="true"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceRequests}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSR}"
            SelectionMode="Single"SelectionUnit="FullRow">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="auto"
                    Binding="{Binding BoundToSelected}"
                    Header="BoundToSelected" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="auto"
                    Binding="{Binding BoundToVMProperty}"
                    Header="BoundToVMProperty" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Changes made to the textbox bound to the SelectedItem Property is reflected back to the DataGrid, but changes made to the textbox bound to the VM Property do not.

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace PhoneAssistant.WPF.Features.ServiceRequests;

public sealed partial class ServiceRequestsMainViewModel : ObservableObject, IServiceRequestsMainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceRequest> ServiceRequests { get; } = new();

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ServiceRequest _selectedSR;

    partial void OnSelectedSRChanged(ServiceRequest value)
    {
        VmProperty = value.BoundToVMProperty;
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    // Neither of these notifies update the datagrid
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(ServiceRequests))]   
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(SelectedSR))]
    private string _vmProperty;
    
    partial void OnVmPropertyChanged(string value)
    {
        SelectedSR.BoundToVMProperty = value;
    }

    public Task LoadAsync()
    {
        ServiceRequests.Add(new ServiceRequest() { Id = 1, BoundToSelected = "SomeValue1", BoundToVMProperty = "AnotherValee1"});
        ServiceRequests.Add(new ServiceRequest() { Id = 2, BoundToSelected = "SomeValue2", BoundToVMProperty = "AnotherValee2" });
        ServiceRequests.Add(new ServiceRequest() { Id = 3, BoundToSelected = "SomeValue3", BoundToVMProperty = "AnotherValee3" });
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}


public sealed class ServiceRequest
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string BoundToSelected { get; set; }
    public string BoundToVMProperty { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get these changes to update the datagrid?

Comment: I can see backing field but I can't see `SelectedSR` anywhere? have you tried just raising OnPropertyChanged()?

Comment: The CommunityToolkit.MVVM uses code generators to create all the INotifyPropertyChanged code.

Answer (score 0):

You bind the DataGrid to BoundToVMProperty but TextBox to VmProperty

```
 <DataGridTextColumn
                Width="auto"
                Binding="{Binding BoundToVMProperty}"
                Header="BoundToVMProperty" />

 <TextBox
         Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,5,0"
         Text="{Binding VmProperty}" />
```

change the TextBox Binding

```
     <TextBox
         Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,5,0"
         Text="{Binding SelectedSR.BoundToVMProperty }" />
```

Comment: This is not the answer to my question.
Why do updated to changes to the textbox bound to SelectedSR.BoundToSelected get pushed back to the grid but change to the textbox bound to VmProperty do not.
What attribute am I missing from VMProperty that automatically gets added to an ObservableCollection?

Comment: Because you binding the DataGridTextColumn to SelectedSR.BoundToVMProperty and your textbox to VmProperty. So changes in the VmProperty is not pushed to SelectedSR.BoundToVMProperty which in turn does not update the DataGridTextColumn component, when you change the value in the textbox.